# comparing with two maximum of columns get one row

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table test with columns as id , month, year . i need to get id where maximum of month and maximum of year in one query.

for example

```
id     month   year
1       10     2012

2        9     2013
```

my result should be id 2 .

first checks with year based on that maximum month based on these to i need to get id

i give query like this in MySQL

```
 select id from book where MAX(month) and MAX(year);
```

its produce error

Comment: How you need Maximum month is 10 , where max year 2013. Then what you need? By Year Or By Month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort using month and year:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cccf/7)

```
SELECT id
FROM   books
ORDER  BY year DESC, month DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: Yeap, but don't forget- if you need to get MAX value, you have to sort with DESC ;)

Answer (score 2):

For this type of query, `order by` and `limit` are the best approach.  You seem to want the latest date, so start with the year (in descending order) and then month (in descending order):

```
select *
from book
order by year desc, month desc
limit 1
```

In particular, you *don't* want the maximum month and maximum year.  Based on your desired results, you want the most recent/latest month.

Answer (score 1):

You can just ORDER BY year, month with DESC keyword :)

```
SELECT id 
FROM book 
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC 
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: And you need to sort by year first :)